# Does GC handle unpointed parts of arrays

Tags: go, garbage-collection

Let's say that we created a slice this way:

```
arr := make([]byte, 0, 10)
arr = append(arr, []byte{1, 1, 1}...)
```

And then we want to free 7 tail bytes:

```
arr = arr[:len(arr)]
```

We leave the slices' tail unreachable. Will GC simply claim this memory free on the next sweep iteration? Or something else will happen with an underlying array(e.g. `copy()`, memory will not be freed at all)?

Comment: It's not unreachable: https://play.golang.org/p/-ejhWDI_0zs

Comment: @JimB I guess, that in such short program gc sweep doesn't happen

Comment: No, it's part of the slice specification, `arr[:len(arr)]` doesn't change the capacity. GC will collect the backing array when it's no longer used.

Comment: @JimB actually, my question was named **Does** GC handle... Guess, that it's better to revert this edit :)

Comment: The expression `arr[:len(arr)]` does not make the tail unreachable. For example, one can write `tail := arr[len(arr):cap(arr)]` to get the tail.

Comment: @RobLucci No, because per the specification, you can access the capacity of a slice as a contiguous block of memory. The memory in your example is not unreachable.

Comment: You allocate memory once, slice just contains offsetted data.

Comment: `arr = arrz[1:]` equals a C equivalent `array += 1` (considering that array is pointer). Golang just has abstraction for this as struct with additional fields like cap and len.

Comment: There's even a post in the official wiki about this https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

Comment: @LaevusDexter `array = array[:1]` is somewhat equivalent to C `array += 1`, but note that Go does not have the equivalent of C's  `array -= 1`.  Slicing with a positive offset can make elements before the offset unreachable and therefore eligible for collection.  Whether that happens or not is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say that we created a slice this way:
>
> ```
> arr := make([]byte, 0, 10)
> arr = append(arr, []byte{1, 1, 1}...)
> ```
>
> And then we want to free 7 tail bytes:
>
> ```
> arr = arr[:len(arr)]
> ```

---

You can't; the Go GC does not do partial frees. The 10 bytes will stay allocated until there are no references to any part of the 10 bytes.

For example, to free tail bytes,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    arr := make([]byte, 0, 10)
    arr = append(arr, []byte{1, 1, 1}...)

    // free tail bytes:
    fmt.Println(len(arr), cap(arr), &arr[0], arr)
    arr = append(make([]byte, 0, len(arr)), arr...)
    fmt.Println(len(arr), cap(arr), &arr[0], arr)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/l6cbiBoMf4j

Output:

```
3 10 0x414020 [1 1 1]
3 3 0x414050 [1 1 1]
```

---

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)